# Exporting pyplot graphs and adding textual part to assemble a report document

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to python. I am reading few **`.csv`** files and getting data. Now I have to mix these and generate various graphs. I used `matplotlib.pyplot` to generate graphs. Now I want to display each graph in file (could be **`.pdf`** or **`.doc`**) along with some text results for each of the graphs. What is the best way to achieve this? **`pyplot`** graphs can be converted to a single `.pdf` files, but adding text in those files is difficult.

```
EDIT:
```

Following codes are not working

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import BytesIO
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch,cm
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
y=np.ones(10)
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        y[j]=randint(0,9)
    #x[i]=y
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
    plt.plot(y)
    print(y)
    plt.ylabel('some numbers')
    imgdata=BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(imgdata, format='png')
    imgdata.seek(0)
    Image=ImageReader(imgdata)
    c.drawImage(Image, cm, cm, inch, inch)
    c.showPage()
c=canvas.Canvas('test1.pdf')
c.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Python is a powerful can-do ecosystem

So, first generate the `pyplot` part of the art-work:

[image]

Next, save it ( using iostream, without a file-proxy, is a smarter way ).

Finally, use Python PDF tools of your choice, to control the report document layout, content and assembly management tasks. Options are many: **`pypdf`**, **`pyfpdf`**, **`reportlab`** and many others -- while preferences are yours.

[image]

Comment: What is iostream? Is it suppose to save graphs as an image file and then inserting it in pdf? I tried using reportlab but could not insert my pyplot in canvas or as render.

Comment: No, iostream is a means of avoiding fileIO operations, i.e. a way to work without a need to have to save an interim file.

Comment: Please see the given codes. the generated pdf file is getting corrupted.

Comment: according to StackOverflow principles, you shall rather isolate the issue and open it as a new [Question]